# I am trying to hide the back arrow navigation button but it does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

***hello guys I am trying to hide the back-arrow navigation button but it does not work***

```
function MyStack(){
  return(
      <Stack.Navigator
       screenOptions={{
         headerTitle:null,
         headerTransparent:true,
         topBar:{
           backButton:{
                  noBorder: true,
                  backButton: {visible: false},
                  leftButtons: [],
           }
         }
       }}
      >
      <Stack.Screen name="Index" component={IndexScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="drawer" component={Drawer} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Comment: It is a easy task which is already provided in the documentation, please look into it more properly before asking a question here. I have posted the answer below anyway

Answer (score 1):

Set `headerLeft: null` in your `<Stack.Screen>` or `<Stack.Navigator>` options like the below example.

```
function MyStack(){
  return(
      <Stack.Navigator
       screenOptions={{
         headerTitle:null,
         headerTransparent:true,
         headerLeft: null
       }}
      >
      <Stack.Screen options={{headerLeft: null}} name="Index" component={IndexScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="drawer" component={Drawer} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Comment: headerLeft: null Not works for me. Instead, I used an empty View:  ```headerLeft: () => {
        return <View style={{ marginLeft: 50 }}></View>;
}```

Comment: This answer is probably supported in Old version of React Navigation. Now it is changed

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `{headerBackVisible:false}` in the options

You can add it to a specific screen like this

```js
 <Stack.Screen options={{headerBackVisible:false}} name="Index" component={IndexScreen} />
```

Or you can make it for all pages

```js
<Stack.Navigator
       screenOptions={{
         headerTitle:null,
         headerTransparent:true,
         headerLeft: null,
         headerBackVisible: false,
       }}
      >
```